# How do I see the NTusername in trigger?

Tags: sql-server-2005, triggers

SQL Server Profiler shows NtUsername.
How do I see the NTusername in trigger?

I don't understand. SQL Server Profiler shows the Windows username. SUSER_NAME, SUSER_SNAME ORIGINAL_LOGIN, USER, USER_NAME shows the username of the SQL user account. I want what the Profiler is showing. There must be a way if the profiler can do it.

Comment: sys.dm_exec_sessions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I could not find how to get the NTUsername, I used HOST_NAME() which gave me the user's machine name.

SUSER_NAME, SUSER_SNAME, ORIGINAL_LOGIN, USER, USER_NAME all gave me the SQL account username.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me either. I don't understand enough in the area. Although, I do know that it shows the username that I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You use `SUSER_SNAME()`. Not `SUSER_NAME()`. Note the extra **`S`**

- [`SUSER_SNAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174427.aspx) returns the connection user (SQL Server 2000+)
- [`SUSER_NAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187934.aspx) gives the value of [`sys.server_principals.principal_id`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188786.aspx) (SQL Server 2005+)

`SUSER_NAME` will give NULL for a Windows user who connects via a Windows Group, because only the Windows Group has an entry in `sys.server_principals`

Notes:

- you have SUSER_ID and SUSER_SID at the *SQL Server Instance* level which are the opposite
- at the *database* level, you have USER_NAME and DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID (USER_ID is deprecated)
- A SQL login *won't* have an ntusername value in Profiler, because it isn't available

Answer (score 0):

There is no correlation between the NTUserName unless the login is a Windows Authentication login.  But because `suser_name()` is not returning what you want, I'm assuming that you are using SQL Server Authentication.

In which case, I don't believe you can do this.

Comment: Right, if you're using SQL Server authentication, there is no way to get the Windows Auth information (in a trigger or otherwise). If you need to know the Windows account info, you need to make users log in with Windows Auth.

Comment: @AaronBertrand There is probably a way to do it with WMI, but I surely don't know that answer.

Comment: I don't know how - SQL Server can identify your hostname (as passed in) but unless you're logged onto the box where SQL Server is running, that's about as far as it can get. Also consider that with SQL auth there isn't even any guarantee that the SQL Server is in the same domain as the user.

Comment: @Bruno: you're simply using the wrong function... see my answer please

Answer (score 0):

It apears that the protocol used in your case was NamedPipes.

- if NTUserName is not blank and in LoginName you have SQL Login – then it is SQL Authentication Over Named Pipes

-- see http://sqlbg.wordpress.com/2011/05/28/how-to-check-what-sql-server-network-protocol-is-used-by-connections/